# How to retrieve int value from datagrid cell

Tags: c#, wpf

How to extract a value from a datagrid as and integer value? I have a Customer_ID column in my database and it´s connected to my datagrid in a program. i need to extract that value from the datagrid as an integer so i can write a sql query (that vaue is integer value in sql database).Thanks

UPDATE ( this is what i´ve tried):

```
DataRowView dataRow = (DataRowView)vMieten.SelectedItem;


       int index = vMieten.CurrentCell.Column.DisplayIndex;

        string cellValue = dataRow.Row.ItemArray[index].ToString();
```

Comment: Did you try _anything_ so far?

Comment: You have to get a DataRow _dr from DataTable, then based on that DataRow to retrive Customer_ID and then apply int.Parse(_dr["Customer_ID"]. Rgds

Comment: i´ve updated what i´ve tried, but i cant get int out of it

Comment: int a= Convert.tointeger(str)

Answer (score 0):

```
   if (Datagrid.SelectedItems.Count > 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < Datagrid.SelectedItems.Count; i++)
            {
               System.Data.DataRowView selected = 
                       (System.Data.DataRowView)Datagrid.SelectedItems[i];
                 str = Convert.ToString(selected.Row.ItemArray[n]);

                 // get the int value
                 int a = Convert.ToInt32(str);
            }

        }
```

Answer (score -1):

MYCreate a grid say usergrid in the design . 
and in the code try using something like this

```
 MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection("Server=localhost;Database=blah;Uid=root;Pwd=blah");
                string query = "select OrderID  from oders ";
                MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(query, con);
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                da.Fill(ds);
                usergrid.DataSource = ds;
                usergrid.DataBind();
```

for a specific column try something like

```
  DataTable dt = get the data table here //
     DataRow dr = dt.Rows[sample];
                    Convert.ToInt32(dr["MyID"])
```

Comment: This looks like `winforms`, but the question is tagged with `wpf`.

Comment: I dont have a problem creating a datagrid. I need to pull out integer value from the first cell of the grid

Comment: it says DataRow contains no definitions for .Rows

Comment: check this it would help http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/395ce6dc-38b9-49df-869a-83c273f09b90/reading-a-cell-value-in-a-wpf-datagrid?forum=wpf

Comment: Thanks, i can get a value from the cell, but the problem is that rhe value is string type and i can´t convert it to integer